# Notice: Undefined index: Internet explorer only

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I am trying to make a ajax based login system... It works fine in all browser but IE

following error is generated

```
Login error


Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\Server\Apache2\htdocs\php\loginuser.php on line

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\Server\Apache2\htdocs\php\loginuser.php on line

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\Server\Apache2\htdocs\php\loginuser.php on line 
User with this username does not exist
```

Why in the hell IE sucks so bad.. What is wrong with my code...

```
//ajax send login form values
$("#loginform").submit(function(){
var username=$("#username").val();
var password=$("#password").val();
$.post("/php/loginuser.php",{username:username, password:password},function(result){
$("#err_msg").html(result);                     
});
```

Comment: And your HTML form is...?

Comment: Which version of IE, what does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: could you post your loginuser.php ?

Comment: Html form is basic...

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with JavaScript? The error is from PHP, isn't it?

Comment: What does "form is basic" mean? Show it anyway, no matter how "basic" it seems like.

Comment: yes its php, this is why i sayed "could you post your loginuser.php"

Answer (score 1):

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\Server\Apache2\htdocs\php\loginuser.php on line
```

This means you're trying to get the value of the variable `$username` even though it has never been declared.

Make sure you have a variable named `$username` and make sure it has a value.

```
$username = "";
```

The same thing goes for all the other ones.

You should also use `isset()` to check if the data posted from the client is set or not.

```
$username = isset($_POST["username"]) ? $_POST["username"] : "User not found";
```

Using the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) and `isset`.

If it's not set then something failed in the http process, most likely you failed to give your HTML input elements a proper id so the JavaScript, perhaps, doesn't know what elements you're talking about when you try to reference them at the client side before you send them over.

Make sure you've checked your developer tools, check at what I mentioned and Google the error.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with the post of @Jonast92 but i would not go for an "IF"
instead of i would use

```
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
```

in this case you get the result of the post if its set, and if not its false.

you could do the same with [GET and some filter parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.filter-input.php)